# Boot a phone with a broken power button

Tags: boot

I'm hoping if there are any ways on how should I boot my phone. I've researched multiple ways on booting your phone thru adb but my computer fails to recognize it although I have Samsung Drivers Installed. USB Debugging mode is on since I'm using ADB to install my apps. My phone is Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Plus.

Comment: try to enter download mode with JIG dongle and use the auto-reboot after flash option from Odin

Answer (score 0):

Press the Home button and Volume Down button while plugging in the charger. It should enter Downloading/Recovery mode. Then press the Volume Down button. Your device will power on.